# "Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" with springboot and hibernate search

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-search

I'm trying to have a `Many-to-Many` relation between two entities:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.perso.ez.debate.tag.TagEntity;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.IndexedEmbedded;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "data")
public class DataLightEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "subtitle")
    private String subtitle;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "text", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String text;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "data_tags", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "data_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<TagEntity> tags;

    @Column(name = "icon")
    private String icon;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSubtitle() {
        return subtitle;
    }

    public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public List<TagEntity> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<TagEntity> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DataLightEntity{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", subtitle='" + subtitle + '\'' +
                ", text='" + text + '\'' +
                ", tags=" + tags +
                ", icon='" + icon + '\'' +
                ", date=" + date +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```java
package com.perso.ez.debate.tag;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.perso.ez.debate.data.DataLightEntity;
import com.perso.ez.debate.tag.type.TagTypeEntity;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
public class TagEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "tag")
    private String tag;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = false)
    private TagTypeEntity type;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<DataLightEntity> datas = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public TagTypeEntity getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(TagTypeEntity type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<DataLightEntity> getDatas() {
        return datas;
    }

    public void setDatas(List<DataLightEntity> datas) {
        this.datas = datas;
    }
}
```

I'm using the `@Field` and `@IndexedEmbedded` annotation for my research functionality and the `@JsonIgnore` to avoid an infinite loop.

But, I still getting this error when I'm trying to make a research:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.perso.ez.debate.data.DataLightEntity.tags, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.perso.ez.debate.data.DataLightEntity.tags, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.perso.ez.debate.data.DataLightEntity["tags"])]
```

I don't know what to do. I tried many things but I'm out of ideas.
If anyone has an idea, that would help me a lot.
Thanks!

Comment: @JsonIgnore annotation belong to Jackson so if you serialize / deserialize your entity using Jackson library then only it will get ignored otherwise while default tostring() method will get called on each object in serializing deserializing protocol

Answer (score 0):

Add `fetch: Lazy` to your `DataLightEntity` as below:

```
@IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "data_tags", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "data_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<TagEntity> tags;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, as you have lazily fetch(by default), then while deserializing thhe resultset, you got that error. To overcome those, add this for lazy fetch entity(In this case, as you have many to many relation, add this line for both entity class level I mean after your `@Table annotation` in `DataLightEntity` and `TagEntity` class)

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: did you add this for both classes?